# Database designing for query builder project

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have this project in which user can create queries using web based UI in which there will be list of columns and applicable operators. Later users can edit these queries, too. So I need to store this in database.

I can store query in table as simple string but then editing will be not possible so I need to store it some other way. So I somehow managed to design it following way.

[image: Proposed schema]

So let's say I have to store this query:

```
C1 > 8 AND (C2 <= 7 OR (C4 LIKE '%all%' AND (C1 > 15 OR C2 <= 3)))
```

where: C denotes some column

If I have to store it in DB as shown in image,

- I would group each condition and store it in sub_operand table
- **then there will be recursive mapping entry in op_master table for each entry in sub_operand table**
- finally there will be master entry in op_master

But it seems too much complicated to handle insert and update. Can someone help me with this? I am very much stuck here.

**UPDATE: I think I am missing something here in schema. It won't work as I have thought. I will update question as soon as I can correct it.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about the way you will use your data structure to represent the tree structure of a formula. See my answer to [Logical Expressions rules in relational datamodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309214/logical-expressions-rules-in-relational-datamodel/36311435#36311435) for this aspect. (But your question is not a duplicate of that one.)

I don't see the complication in inserting and updating. The only complicated aspect I can see is the GUI for your users to enter and edit these recursive formulas. It's somewhat complicated as, due to the unbounded width and depth of the formula, you can't just define *one* set of drop-down fields for column and operand selection, but the count of GUI elements will need to grow as the user increases the width and depth.

Once this is solved, you will have the following architecture:

```
Formula GUI --buildFormula--> Formula --storeFormula--> Database
            <--display-------         <-readFormula----
```

This means you have some abstract representation of a Formula in your domain layer, again some tree, that you use to actually evaluate these formulas. And you need to persist Formulas in the database. The operations propagating formulas from the GUI to the domain and further to the database, and the other way round, are also shown.

As I said, the GUI is the most complex part. Having a formula representation on the GUI, sending it to the domain and building its identically structured counterpart in your programming language isn't a problem. If the formula got edited, i.e. if it had a previous structure that now got modified by the user, I wouldn't try to incrementally update the domain object, but just throw it away and build it up from scratch. The same holds for storing in the database: Delete all parts of it and store it as a whole.

Reading is straightforward too, again with some effort in building the GUI representation.

By the way, it isn't strictly necessary to represent all subterms of your formula as records in the database. If you will never query on those subterms, but just store and read the formula as a whole, and if you never have a query like `select all formulas using a specific column`, it would be sufficient to store a formula as a single string.

Comment: Thanks TAM. I agree that GUI is complicated and I am planning to implement a tree and there will be DFS approach. Thouhj I liked your suggestion about deleting existing record while editing one. This will save lots of effort. But., my concern is, is there any way I can improve this design or is it okay?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence about the "recursive mapping entry in sub_operand table". In any case, the solution to which the link in my answer points is the textbook solution for representing formulas of arbitrary width and depth, so if you take that one you should be on the safe side.

Comment: Oops, I am sorry, I have modified info.