# Save concatenated conditional expressions in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

[image: Conditions table structure]

Hi im trying to do an event alarms system that It is thought to depend on a list of undeterminated concatened conditional rules. 
Here comes my logical problem, when im trying to structure the database to save this conditional rules in a table, i cant figure out how exactly trace the hierarchy of the expressions, for example if i wanna save the conditión

 `[(1 =< 2 && 2 == 2) || (0 == 0 || 1 == 1)] && (1 == 1)` 
or any undeterminated number of concatened conditional rules. Can anybody help o almost understand me ?

P.D: Sorry my bad english (:

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags (add back the tag for the database you are really using).  Your question could also be cleaned up so other people can understand what you want to do -- sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical Expressions rules in relational datamodel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309214/logical-expressions-rules-in-relational-datamodel)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using SQL Server

Comment: Do you need to query or modify individual pieces of the expression (as opposed to always retrieving or storing the whole expression to the database)? Do you need to reference entities in the database from your conditional expression? If the answer to **both** of these questions is "no", then the expression is just a string (**from the data management perspective**, not necessarily from the application perspective) and you can store it as such in the database.

Comment: in the future it should be able to be modified, as part of configuration conditions, that is why im trying to avoid a single string entry